# Is there a way to make the keyboard not to pop up as a default in a particular screen?

Tags: android

I have an Activity screen with a form that has a text area, and text below the form. When the screen opens, for some reason, the keyboard pops up automatically and blocks the bottom part of the screen for the user, causing some confusion since they don't get to see the text that is below.

Is there a way to not make the keyboard pop up by default and only have it pop up when the user clicks inside the text area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file use this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem thanks, I am a bit surprised it should be in the manifest file.  And reason it is not done in the layout as the other answer suggests?  Thanks! :)

Comment: You can do this ssing XML file. But it is tough to do that.

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem ah I see...so the way you suggest - if its hidden as default, it will pop up eventually when the textarea is tapped and put it focus, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this attributes on the textarea in your xml file

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: thanks - so this seems like it will enable the keyboard be attached to the textarea, but will it make the keyboard not appear by default?